# Debugging VB code in aspx files

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am converting an old asp project to a new .NET project. Now, all vb code are inside aspx files, and we are on the process of moving all vb script from aspx files to .vb files. My problem is, I can't debug the vb script inside most of the aspx files. All my friends don't have this problem. I think the problem is with vb text editor.

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

Is there anyway, I can make visual studio understand that aspx files have vb script inside them.

can't debug the code

[image]

can debug the code

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using to view the page? You may need to "Enable Script Debugging" (IE) or similar for other browsers...

Comment: I am using IE 8. I am sorry but I don't understand how does the browser relate to my problem. It should be a visual studio problem. Also, Enable Scirpt Debugging is checked on my browser. P.S. The code complie and runs fine but I can't debug the code!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint on a particular line in the VB Script.  If that line is hit you will see Visual Studio highlight that line.

Comment: Okay, I understand your comment. However, when I try to debug any line visual studio display this is not a valid location for a breakpoint.  I can't set a breakpoint anywhere in my file, even if it is a call to a procedure, if statement, while statement, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual Studio Debugger to debug a .vbs (vbscript) file executed with cScript.exe by using the //X flag at the command line. To debug MyTest.vbs

> cscript.exe MyTest.vbs //X

The //X will set a breakpoint and invoke the "select a debugger"  dialog where you can choose Visual Studio and step into your vbs code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, My vb code are inside the aspx files. I don't have vbs files at all!!

Comment: Basically, it should be worked. Make sure that if you use IE than in browser's settings you turn off "Disable script debugging" in other case it should be possible to attach process "iexplorer" with type "script"

Comment: Disable script debugging is off and still I can't debug the code. Also, I don't enabling script debugging on IE 8 will resolve the problem. My project runs fine and I can view all the pages. However, I can't debug the code!!! I think it is a visual studio problem.